# Manage a simple list of items in frontend as a registered user (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, frontend

Me and my friends like to read books, and I thought to create a simple wordpress theme, so each of us could post his own list of read books.

Each person would have a registered user, so they could manage the list created.
Not all of them knows to use wordpress, so i'm thinking to a simple method, like a button in frontend for adding a new list.
After the list is created, the ability to add or remove list items in frontend, or adding rating and tags for each list item.

I'm not asking the code, just some guidelines to know from where to start, or if is possible.
I'm learning to create wordpress themes, so this would be a good opportunity to gain more experience.

If there's already a plugin who does that, i'd love to hear about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using BuddyPress as a solution.  It easily allows users to create and manage accounts.  There are also a lot of free plugins that perform similar things to which you are referring.

https://buddypress.org/

Comment: Thank you! I think the best aproach would be to create a custom post type and then display each author's posts in a separate list. That way, i can add a featured image for each book(post), tags, category and rating, and ofcourse - some info which can be revealed when opening that post.